# SVN Cleanup Risks

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

As far as I understand, the SVN cleanup command releases stable locking form working copy.

Can I execute the cleanup as a regular routine before SVN update command?
What are the risks of cleanup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned in the following link:

http://jtdan.com/vcs/svn/tortoise/1.6/TortoiseSVN/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html

> "If a Subversion command cannot complete successfully, perhaps due to
>   server problems, your working copy can be left in an inconsistent
>   state. In that case you need to use TortoiseSVN → Cleanup on the
>   folder. It is a good idea to do this at the top level of the working
>   copy.
>
> Cleanup has another useful side effect. If a file date changes but its
>   content doesn't, Subversion cannot tell whether it has really changed
>   except by doing a byte-by-byte comparison with the pristine copy. If
>   you have a lot of files in this state it makes acquiring status very
>   slow, which will make many dialogs slow to respond. Executing a
>   Cleanup on your working copy will repair these “broken” timestamps and
>   restore status checks to full speed."

Many users have reported about slow cleanup which consumes a lot of time and memory in case the working copy does not update due to stale locks.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. Do you mean it is better to update the working copy and then clenup?

Comment: Performing an SVN cleanup not really necessary unless your working copy gets locked due to improper updates or server problems. Perform an update alone and you're good to go.

Comment: @user3165438, don't forget to accept an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks. I still do not understand what should be the first action in case of a problematic working copy: the update is first or the cleanup? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case of a problematic working copy, SVN wont let you update unless you perform a cleanup...

Comment: In Short: **WorkingCopy --> SVN Update --> Good to go** else **WorkingCopy --> SVN Update --> Uh oh! Working copy locked! Requires cleanup --> SVN Cleanup --> SVN Update --> Good to go**. As I said, its not always necessary to perform a cleanup unless you encounter some problems. Hope this helps.